# Why is my UITableViewCell imageView image disappearing?

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage, imageview

I have an image in a cell's imageView, but If I scroll the uitableview up so that that particular cell goes off of the screen, then let it come back down, the imageView disappears.

How can I fix this?[image]

The left column is the tableview untouched, the middle column is the tableview pulled up, the right column is the tableview released

Comment: Could you post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code? It could be any number of things.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin mentioned, your problem may be in the way you set the image. Are you creating an imageView and assigning it to the cell's imageView property or the image inside the property? without looking at the code, I would suggest checking what happens when the cell is created. in the `cell == nil` case. Hope it helps.